# LICENSE file required?

Tags: mit, license-notice, website

When creating a new [Gatsby site](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/quick-start/) with `gatsby new gatsby-site`, there exists the file `LICENSE`.

`LICENSE`

```
The MIT License (MIT)

Copyright (c) 2015 gatsbyjs

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
SOFTWARE.
```

If I delete the `src/` directory and all files inside, do I still need to keep the `LICENSE` file?

I plan on creating a open source site created with `Gatsby` (with no explicit license stated so that any users who want to use my code must contact me first)

The only files I will keep are `gatsby-config.js`, `package.json`, `.gitignore`, `.prettierignore`, and `.prettierrc`. These are very simple files to create, so I could delete them and rewrite them myself.

Comment: "with no explicit license stated so that any users who want to use my code must contact me first" is in stark contradiction to "open-source".

Answer (score 2):

Technically, as long as you have Gatsby-generated files, you need to retain the license information that they are under. However, you **are** allowed to amend the LICENSE file to make it clear which files that MIT license applies to and what licenses apply to the rest of the files.

On the other hand, if the files you mention can be written only in a very few limited ways to achieve the desired effects, to the level that they can easily be auto-generated, then those files are probably not copyrightable and thus not subject to any copyright license. If those were the last files remaining of what Gatsby generated, then you can remove the LICENSE file.